# How to make ggplot2 graphics compatible with black-and-white printing (photocopy friendly) in R?

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2

Is there a way to convert `ggplot2` plots into black-and-white versions without rewriting much of their code, so that the black-and-white versions remain readable?

For instance, to replace `scale_fill_gradient` with `scale_fill_grey`? Or automatically make photocopy-friendly transformations as sites like http://colorbrewer2.org/ advise. (Unfortunately, textures are not an option, as `ggplot2` doesn't support them.)

It's clearly possible with `if ... else` and custom functions, but is there a more general solution?

Comment: I find the preset colors in `color_discrete` bad in that sense that they won´t stand out in BW printing. One way around this is to use sequential color schemes or adjust the colors manually using `hsv`function. Depends on how the plot looks like and how many colors your have.

Answer (score 2):

My second line in every ggplot figure I make is

```
theme_bw()
```

so

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Perhaps, if it's in every ggplot figure, then `theme_set(theme_bw())` would suffice? (I actually use this theme as well, but have to combine it with color `fill` and `color`, hence the initial question arises.)

Comment: @Anton I think I see where you're getting at. I don't think you can have an out of the box solution for this. When I send materials for print (in BW) they always ask me to convert it to gray scale. You never know what will go wrong. I think you're stuck with writing a special version of your plot.

Comment: Greg Snow gave a tip about `col2grey` function from `TeachingDemos` package in a related question (see below). It´s not exactly what you are after but could make finding the colors that convert to grey scale and are still distinguishable easier. Btw, writing a greyscale 'color' palette for ggplot should be quite easy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682542/convert-colors-to-imitate-greyscale-printing?lq=1