# Convert colors to imitate greyscale printing

Tags: r, graphics, colors

When reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679635/how-to-make-ggplot2-graphics-compatible-with-black-and-white-printing-photocopy), I started to think whether it would be possible to convert colors to imitate an average greyscale printer (assuming that your screen is calibrated)? Finding an approvable approximation would save paper.

For example, how to convert these colors to see whether the light and dark blues and reds can be differentiated on paper?

```
temp <- rgb2hsv(239, 138, 98, maxColorValue=255)
Rl <- hsv(h = temp[1,], s = 0.5, v = 1)
Rd <- hsv(h = temp[1,], s = 0.5, v = 0.4)
temp <- rgb2hsv(103, 169, 207, maxColorValue=255)
Cl <- hsv(h = temp[1,], s = temp[2,], v = 1)
Cd <- hsv(h = temp[1,], s = temp[2,], v = 0.4)

plot(1:4, type = "p", col = c(Rl, Rd, Cl, Cd), pch = 19, cex = 8, xlim = c(0,5), ylim = c(0,5))
```

[image]

Comment: If you are working in hsv, you can just set the saturation to be zero to convert to greyscale.

Comment: If you want the colours to be indistinguishable to humans when in greyscale, then work in an hcl palette, and set the chroma to zero.

Comment: Setting saturation to 0 on hsv scale makes `Rl` to disappear, but it does not if you try printing the plot with a greyscale printer. Maybe the printer adjusts the colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an HCL palette with chroma set to zero to create greyscale values that are indistinguishable to the human eye.

```
library(colorspace)
n <- 10
cols <- rainbow_hcl(n)
plot(seq_len(n), cex = 5, pch = 20, col = cols)

greys <- rainbow_hcl(n, c = 0)
plot(seq_len(n), cex = 5, pch = 20, col = greys)
```

If you want to generate the greys from your original colours, use the `scales` package.

```
library(scales)
greys2 <- col2hcl(cols, c = 0)
plot(seq_len(n), cex = 5, pch = 20, col = greys2)
```

Comment: Why indistinguishable?

Comment: Your question asks if the colours "can be differentiated on paper".  HCL corrects for the fact that in HSV blues look darker than yellows with the same saturation and value.

Comment: Ok, thanks for `scales` package. So the answer to my question would be something like: `cols <- c(Rl, Rd, Cl, Cd); library(scales); greys <- col2hcl(cols, c = 0); plot(seq_along(cols), cex = 5, pch = 20, col = greys)`. I do not have a printer to check whether the colors turned to the grey scale look approximately the same on the screen and paper at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

The `desaturate()` function in the `colorspace package can also be used to convert colors to their gray levels only. This collapses chroma (colorfulness) in the HCL (or polar CIELUV) representation of the colors.

```
plot(1:4, type = "p",
  col = colorspace::desaturate(c(Rl, Rd, Cl, Cd)),
  pch = 19, cex = 8, xlim = c(0,5), ylim = c(0,5))
```

[image: plot with gray colors]

Answer (score 2):

The `col2grey` (and/or `col2gray`) function in the TeachingDemos package uses one common method for doing this.  The idea is to see what your colors will look like when printed or copied in grayscale instead of color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the 3 conversion algorithms outlined [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/), and just determine if they're outside whatever tolerance you think is too similar.